# Windows 10 Home/Pro Does it really run in a VM on your home computer?

Tags: windows-10, operating-systems, hyper-v

Some people at my office told me that Windows 10 doesn't run directly on the hardware like older versions of Windows. That windows sets up a hyper-V and runs the OS in a VM. Is this true and what pro's / con's does this have on windows 10 in comparison to other OS's and older versions of windows.

All attempts to google this resulted in info on how to fun windows on a server hyper-v and didn't tell me much how the normal user versions of windows are layered on the hardware.

Comment: The people in your office are mistaken.  Hyper-V is an optional feature of Windows 10 Professional.  You cannot enable it on Windows 10 Home.  An answer listing pros/cons of Windows 10 is out of scope here at Superuser.  The list would be purely based on opinion.

Comment: I think that *"some people"* simply had a miscommunication that got lost in translation over time.  I am going to take an educated guess and say that those people originally [heard about the Xbox One game console utilizing a variation of Windows 10 along with Hyper-V](https://www.thurrott.com/xbox/7302/xbox-360-backwards-compatibility-on-xbox-one-preview) technologies to provide a virtual version of the Xbox 360 console for backwards compatibility with legacy games.

Comment: That must be what happened. maybe they mistaken windows 10 and the xbox console.

Comment: If you enable Hyper-V on your Windows 10 Pro host, yes, the original OS is moved to the "parent partition" which is a special VM.  Any other VMs you run will be in the child partition and more like a regular VM.  Wikipedia has a good graphic of this.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-V